# how to dynamically switch between development & production WPF references

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, web-services

how do i programatically do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your reference paths depending on you environment then you can edit your proj file and use a condition with your reference:

```
<Reference Include="YourReferenceHere"  Condition=="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
  <HintPath>someFolder\yourDllForDebug.dll</HintPath>
</Reference

<Reference Include="YourReferenceHere"  Condition=="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <HintPath>someFolder\yourDllForRelease.dll</HintPath>
</Reference
```

So in this case, when you build as debug, your compiler will use someFolder\yourDllForDebug.dll for the reference.  When you build as Release, your compiler will use someFolder\yourDllForRelease.dll.

Comment: this is for library references. i was talking about WCF web references.